# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218 what can I do?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm currently working on a forum system (laravel 5.3) and I get an error, probably because I have something set wrong in my routes settings.

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/index', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/thread/{id}', 'ThreadController@showThread')->name('thread_detail');
Route::get('/privacybeleid', 'PagesController@privacyPolicy');
Route::get('/over-ons', 'PagesController@about');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

Route::get('/thread/nieuw', 'ThreadController@showForm')->name('thread_form');
Route::post('/thread', 'ThreadController@create')->name('create_thread');
Route::post('/thread/{id}/reply', 'CommentController@create')->name('create_comment');
});
```

When I want to see a thread (website.com/thread/{id}) then I get no error, everything works as it should. But when I want to add a new comment on a topic (website.com/thread/{id}/reply) or create a new topic (website.com/thread/nieuw) I get the following error:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

I've tried to change **Route::get** to **Route::post** (and vice versa), but then I get another error.

When I go to website.com/thread/nieuw , then I see nothing (page does not exist). Even if I have a session (logged in).

By the way: there are tips for the routes/web.php? Let me know

*Note: I am dutch so "nieuw" means "new"*

Comment: Try putting you default route ```Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index')->name('index');``` at the bottom, not before any other route.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the same error message. But I will adjust it correctly.

Comment: why not use Route::post('/thread/reply/{id}',..) instead of as incase of yours??

Comment: can you show your form in views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this route:

```
Route::post('/thread/{id}/reply', 'CommentController@create')->name('create_comment');
```

Before this one:

```
Route::get('/thread/{id}', 'ThreadController@showThread')->name('thread_detail');
```

Comment: If this will not work, please show the form which you're trying to submit to `create_comment` route.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Thread;
use App\Comment;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    public function create($id, Request $req)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $thread = Thread::findOrFail($id);
        $body = $req->get('body');
        $comment = new Comment([
            'body' => $body
        ]);
        $comment->user_id = $user->id;
        $thread->comments()->save($comment);
        return redirect()->route('thread_detail', ['id' => $thread->id]);
    }
}
```

My commentcontroller

Comment: Please keep your code inside your question with edits. Not as answers

Comment: I'll pay attention  for that next time

Alexey Mezenin: You mean in my views?

Comment: @Sygun yes, form from the view

Comment: I think I have the solution: the responses are sent within the thread page itself so an route is not necessary (I guess).

But why I can't create a new thread? There is a page in my views where you to create a topic, but when you are logged in, the page /thread/nieuw is not found.

Comment: You still need the route.

Comment: Indeed, now I understand at last. The route is still used for posting comments from the thread page.

 But how can I or hide the error message when people go to http://website.com/thread/1/reply while no reply has been sent? Is it possible there to make a 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to check Edit form method

```
{{ Form::open(['class' => 'form-horizontal', 'route' => ['create_comment', $thread->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) }}
```